# Paper: "appear at the conference" vs "appear in the conference"

Tags: prepositions

Continuing [Publish a paper "in" or "on" a conference proceedings, or journal](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15043/publish-a-paper-in-or-on-a-conference-proceedings-or-journal):

I presented a summary of my results in a talk during some conference X in 2017. How do I write about it?

> A preliminary version of this paper appeared at the conference X'17.

or

> A preliminary version of this paper appeared in the conference X'17.

What's the correct preposition?

Comment: Peter's answer is good.  Just for completeness re: "at" vs. "in", "at" goes to location or attendance.  The audience appears at the conference, and the information is available at the conference.  But it could mean that the author had some copies in the trunk of his car and would hand you one at the conference if you asked for it.  "In" goes to the paper being part of the conference content.  You might use "in" to describe it as being part of a presentation, included in the proceedings, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your description might read

> A preliminary version of this paper **was presented at** the conference X'17.

You "**appeared**" at the conference to "**present**" your paper.